# Adding an Attachement to VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here's the update. The code works fine, but once i enter the path it stops functioning, which makes me think the path is incorrect? I'm not sure what else to do, should I alter the path to where its in my documents or desktop?

```
Sub BLS()
Dim wkbReminderList As Workbook
Dim wksReminderList As Worksheet
Dim lngNumberOfRowsInReminders As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim strEmail As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String
Dim sAttcmnt1 As String, sAttcmnt2 As String, sAttcmnt3 As String
Set wkbReminderList = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksReminderList = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

lngNumberOfRowsInReminders = _
         wksReminderList.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lngNumberOfRowsInReminders

    If wksReminderList.Cells(i, 7) = "" And _
       wksReminderList.Cells(i, 3) <= Date Then

            strEmail = wksReminderList.Cells(i, 6).Value
            strSubject = "Your BLS Certification is Expiring within 60 Days"
            strBody = "Hello," & vbCrLf & _
      " Your BLS Certification is expiring within 60 days."

        sAttcmnt1 = "C:\Keycodes.pdf"

           If SendAnOutlookEmail(strEmail, _
                      strSubject, _
                      strBody, _
                      sAttcmnt1, _
                      sAttcmnt2, _
                      sAttcmnt3) Then
                wksReminderList.Cells(i, 7) = Date
            End If

    ElseIf wksReminderList.Cells(i, 8) = "" And _
           wksReminderList.Cells(i, 4) <= Date Then

            strEmail = wksReminderList.Cells(i, 6).Value
            strSubject = "BLS is Expiring in 30 Days!!!"
            strBody = "other text here..."
            If SendAnOutlookEmail(strEmail, strSubject, strBody) Then
                wksReminderList.Cells(i, 8) = Date
            End If
    End If

Next i

End Sub

Private Function SendAnOutlookEmail(strAddress As String, _
                                    strSubject As String, _
                                    strBody As String, _
                                    Optional sAtt1 As String, _
                                    Optional sAtt2 As String, _
                                    Optional sAtt3 As String) As Boolean
SendAnOutlookEmail = False

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.session.Logon "Outlook"
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error GoTo ErrorOccurred
 With OutMail
    .To = strAddress
    .Subject = strSubject
    .Body = strBody
    If sAtt1 <> "" Then .Attachments.Add = sAtt1
    If sAtt2 <> "" Then .Attachments.Add = sAtt2
    If sAtt3 <> "" Then .Attachments.Add = sAtt3
    .Send
End With
SendAnOutlookEmail = True

Continue:
    On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Exit Function

ErrorOccurred:
    Resume Continue
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying? (**TIRED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim strEmail As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String
    Dim sAttcmnt1 As String, sAttcmnt2 As String, sAttcmnt3 As String

    '
    '~~> Set values of variables here
    '
    strEmail = "Sid@sid.com"
    strSubject = "Blah Blah"
    strBody = "Blah Blah"
    sAttcmnt1 = "C:\Test.txt"
    '
    ' ~~> and so on
    '

    If SendAnOutlookEmail(strEmail, _
                          strSubject, _
                          strBody, _
                          sAttcmnt1, _
                          sAttcmnt2, _
                          sAttcmnt3) Then
        '
        '~~> Do Something
        '
    End If
End Sub

Private Function SendAnOutlookEmail(strAddress As String, _
                                    strSubject As String, _
                                    strBody As String, _
                                    Optional sAtt1 As String, _
                                    Optional sAtt2 As String, _
                                    Optional sAtt3 As String) As Boolean
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
    With OutMail
        .To = strAddress
        .Subject = strSubject
        .Body = strBody
        If sAtt1 <> "" Then .Attachments.Add sAtt1
        If sAtt2 <> "" Then .Attachments.Add sAtt2
        If sAtt3 <> "" Then .Attachments.Add sAtt3
        .Send
    End With

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Function
```

Comment: the code functions fine in addition to the previous, however once I add the path for the attachment sAtt1 "C:\....." it stops functioning.

Comment: What is the exact value that you set for `sAttcmnt1`

Comment: once i add a path i loose functionality. this is what my path looks like.     With OutMail
        .To = strAddress
        .Subject = strSubject
        .Body = strBody
        If sAtt1 <> "C:\Keycodes.pdf" Then .Attachments.Add = sAtt1

Comment: You see the sub sample() and in that `Set values of variables here`. That is where you have to set your variables

Comment: Does it mean that "It Worked" :P

Comment: damn this is weird, so the code functions fine until i enter a path for the attachment, I put the file right in my c drive folder so it would be easy to do...the path looks like this. C:\Keycodes.pdf

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code that you are using?

Comment: The problem was the "=" sign in `If sAtt1 <> "" Then .Attachments.Add = sAtt1`. Same for the other 2. Just remove that and it will work

Comment: Also do not use `.Send`. Use `.Display`

Comment: Yes its working perfectly! I appreciate all the help!